# accessing plan table from another scheme

Tags: oracle, optimization

I don't have update or insert access to a specific scheme.  I want to be able to run my analyzer in one region and place the plan in another.  So something like this:

Region1 is where tables are. 
Region2 is where I have access to the plan table.

I want to run a sql like
explain plan INTO region2.plan_table for 
select * from region1.sometable

But when I do the above statement it says region2.plan_table doesn't exist.

But if I do this:
alter session set current_schema=region2;
select * from plan_table

I see data!

Any thoughts?
Thanks
Saro

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  What does `SELECT object_name, object_type, owner where object_name = 'PLAN_TABLE'` return?  Recent versions of Oracle by default, and many systems before it became a default, would create a central `PLAN_TABLE`, grant access to that table to `PUBLIC`, and create a public synonym for it.  I'm not certain that the last query is actually selecting from the `REGION2` schema's table and not from the public synonym.

Comment: I am using 11g. The last query is for sure selecting from region2 because I had only one record and I inserted it.  Your select is missing table name.  Not sure what to put there. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant to select from `ALL_OBJECTS`.  How did you insert 1 row into `REGION2.PLAN_TABLE`?  Are you sure you didn't insert the data into the public synonym?

Comment: I get: PLAN_TABLE SYNONYM PUBLIC PLAN_TABLE TABLE SCGFAD First thing i did was to alter the session:alter session set current_schema=E517518; and then i ran the query accessing the scheme of tables.  select * from SCGFAD.Currencies;
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
This returned me the correct values.  If I dont put the alter statement it will not work.